# How to inherit properties from two super classes in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have an assignment regarding OOP. The question is like this.
There are two types of people - Family people and friends. Then, some of friends are close friends. Both Close friends and family people have birthday which I should write code to wish them happy birthday.
So my design is like this.

```
class People{
String name;
String email;
}
class FamilyPeople extends People{
String birthday ;
String nickname;
}
class Friend extends People{
String job;
}
class CloseFriend extends Friend{
String birthday;
}
```

So in here the variable birthday is present in two classes. Is there any other way to inherit it from a super classs? I feel like this is a bad design.
Any help would be much appreciated. :)

PS - I have also been asked to write a method to wish CloseFriend and FamilyPeople differently. So I can create an interface with a wish() method and implement it in FamilyPeople and CloseFriend classes.

Comment: Why not move the `birthday` to `People`? It seems weird that a `Friend` doesn't have one, but a `CloseFriend` does

Comment: Yeah, this really breaks a bit. You are modelling humans, and every human has a birth date. And the ability to have a job isnt related to whether someone is your friend or not. The job of a business partner might be more interesting to you than the jobs of your friends.

Comment: I am just saying what question asked. It says I can only send wishes to CloseFriend and FamilyPeople. That's why I didn't include it in People.

Comment: However, each People is likely to be a close friend or family to somebody.

Comment: But the problem is I need to have a variable(attribute) which only belongs to CloseFriend and FamilyPeople.

Comment: @carlosbrath No you don't. You need to have a functionality which only belongs to `CloseFriend` and `FamilyPeople`, namely sending wishes; that is usually done with a method. There's nothing stopping you from having the birthday attribute in `Person` - even if you might not use it there.